# Flutter - Could not find a command named “-”

Tags: flutter, dart

has anyone had this problem before?

Or does anyone have a solution?

I faced this problem when I started running a Flutter program. I deleted sdk and re-downloaded it, but to no avail

```
Could not find a command named "-".
Usage: dart <command|dart-file> [arguments]

Global options:
-h, --help                 Print this usage information.
-v, --verbose              Show additional command output.
    --version              Print the Dart SDK version.
    --enable-analytics     Enable analytics.
    --disable-analytics    Disable analytics.

Available commands:
  analyze   Analyze Dart code in a directory.
  compile   Compile Dart to various formats.
  create    Create a new Dart project.
  fix       Apply automated fixes to Dart source code.
  format    Idiomatically format Dart source code.
  migrate   Perform null safety migration on a project.
  pub       Work with packages.
  run       Run a Dart program.
  test      Run tests for a project.
Run "dart help <command>" for more information about a command.
See https://dart.dev/tools/dart-tool for detailed documentation.
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 64
Exited (sigterm)
```

Comment: Hi there, can you add the line you tried to execute on the command line and which led to this error?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**Workaround**
It happens when the flutter and dart sdk is located in C:\ directory and your project is in the different directory like D:\ .
Create project in same directory where your sdks located.

**EDIT:**
If you have the issue, the problem is your sdk path is not set. Check sdk path in android studio and set the paths. Should work.

Comment: Thank you very much it has been resolved,

Do you have an idea how to create a project on D:\ directory and this error does not appear?

Comment: I never witnessed this issue. can you please explain it in details why is it so ?

Comment: The reason for the down votes is that you only needed to include the location of the sdks in your path. There is no need to put your projects in the same directory as them. If that was the case, everything on your pc would need to be in one directory in order to work.